# How to change Dx and Dy of pspicture grid?

Tags: pstricks

I don't want to use `\psaxes`, `\psgrid`, or manually recreate my own grid with `multido`, etc.

I just want to reuse the available grid of `pspicture`. Is there any option to change `Dx` and `Dy` such that the grid labels can be multiple of 5, for example, instead of 1?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\psset{unit=5mm}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridlabels=8pt,
    gridfont=Arial,
    %   
    gridcolor=red,
    subgridcolor=gray,
    %
    subgriddiv=5,
    %
    gridwidth=.8pt,
    subgridwidth=.4pt,
    %
    griddots=10,
    subgriddots=5,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](25,25)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bonus: how to slightly shift the horizontal labels to the left and vertical labels downward?

Comment: I am a Ti*k*Z man that appreciate your username. Sorry I have nothing to contribute.

Comment: @Symbol1: Thank you for your encouragement. It is more than sufficient.

Comment: The grid scale can be changed by specifying e.g. `unit=20mm` in the `gridstyle`.  But that does not provide control over the labelling.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140382/23215) may be relevant

Comment: 500 ... big player ...... LOL.

Comment: @Chishimotoji: I am Nguyễn Văn Lém.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the version 2.99 (available tomorrow)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\psset{unit=5mm}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=8pt,gridfont=Helvetica,gridcolor=red,subgridcolor=gray,subgriddiv=5,
   gridwidth=.8pt, subgridwidth=.4pt,griddots=10,subgriddots=5,
   griddx=5,
   griddy=2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](25,25)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]